# Real Player was designed using which technology / platform?

Tags: user-interface, device

Real Player UI is definetely the one that I admire.

Need to know its development platform. So that I can request my team to work on same platform to deliver such a nice UI.

Is it .NET, MFC, WCF, WPF etc... etc... ?

Also which is the apt platform to use to make the application work on Window desktop PC, Web-enabled devices, iPhone or whatever.

I know if I use anything that is wrapped around window api, it can work only on device that works on Windows OS. (So definitely no iPhone)
So is there anything that can help **programmers to work on UI application that are device independent**

Comment: `C`, it even runs on `qnx`,- `RTOS`, I remember once I ran this player on `QNX x86 platform` in my system.

Comment: One thing which was can produce UI with cross platform support (Windoms/Linux) is Qt. We can design using Qt creator and QML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice UIs are not that attached to a specific platform, but to having a good designer and user experience designer.

Good UIs can be created in *any* platform.

I am certain there are many *bad* UIs that have been built with the same platform that RealPlayer was built in.

Comment: That's fine. Any idea on Real Player UI design platform.